# Tabs are coming out of the layout

Tags: css, xml, odoo

I have build an form view as shown in below image. All the tabs should display inside that container.

any CSS for that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try `{overflow: hidden}` or `{overflow:scroll}` for container element